# 403 forbidden error while getting indexes from AWS Elastic search using AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-sdk

I am using AWS SDK to connect to elastic search. I am following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-indexing.html

**Other question in this topic were more like permission issues or issue while writing to elasticsearch. For me writing is working fine, only reading is giving me the error**

The POST method works all fine and it is adding the indexes. I am making a GET request for search in the same manner

```
  public void getIndexedRecords(String index,String type,String id,String documentJSON){

        try {
            String endpoint = host +"/" +index+"/_search" ;
            // Builds the request. We need an AWS service, URI, HTTP method, and request
            // body (in this case, JSON).

            Request<?> request = new DefaultRequest<Void>(service);
            request.setEndpoint(new URI(endpoint));
            request.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.GET);
            request.setContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(documentJSON.getBytes()));

            // Retrieves our credentials from the computer. For more information on where
            // this class looks for credentials, see
            // http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html.

            String accessKey = CommonUtils.getCommonProperty("accessKey", "");
            String secretKey = CommonUtils.getCommonProperty("secretKey", "");;
            AWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);

            // Signs the request using our region, service, and credentials. AWS4Signer
            // modifies the original request rather than returning a new request.

            AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
            signer.setRegionName(region);
            signer.setServiceName(service);
            signer.sign(request, creds);
            request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            // Creates and configures the HTTP client, creates the error and response
            // handlers, and finally executes the request.

            ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
            config.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);
            AmazonHttpClient client = new AmazonHttpClient(config);
            System.out.println(client);
            ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext(true);
            ESAWSErrorHandler errorHandler = new ESAWSErrorHandler();
            ESAWSResponseHandler<Void> responseHandler = new ESAWSResponseHandler<Void>();
            client.requestExecutionBuilder().executionContext(context).errorResponseHandler(errorHandler).request(request)
                    .execute(responseHandler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

But it gives me a 403 forbidden error. When I do Curl XGET with my endpoint url I am getting the result. What am I doing wrong here?

> com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException:  (Service: null; Status Code:
>   403; Error Code: Forbidden; Request ID: null)     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1588)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1258)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you would need `es:ESHttpGet` in your ES policy.

Reference:
[Amazon Elasticsearch Service Access Control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html#es-ac-types)
[Control Access to Your Amazon Elasticsearch Service Domain](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-control-access-to-your-amazon-elasticsearch-service-domain/)

Comment: It works and gets me all the records when I change request.setContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(documentJSON.getBytes())); to request.setContent(new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes()));

Comment: I want to send the query parameters in the request (sort, search etc) is there a document I can follow?

Comment: here is a good place to start https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html pls accept the answer if it helped ;)

Comment: How can I send the query parameters in AmazonHttpRequest ?. I tried sending the json in the request body, it didn't work. May be I can ask a separate question for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556491/elasticsearch-aws-search-using-aws-sdk-gives-400-bad-request . Can you please help me with this?